# Gstreamer pipeline stuck in prerolling state when giving only audio to video pipeline

Tags: c, audio, video, gstreamer

If I have a pipeline like:

```
gst-launch filesrc location="/home/dk/Music/Vangelis - Alpha.mp3" !
decodebin2 name=dec !
queue ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink dec. !
queue ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink
```

How to I get it to play when there is no video in the input source, but play video if there is? All I get is:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just set autovideosink's `async-handling` property to true:

```
... ! autovideosink async-handling=true
```

This will allow audiosink to play sound while videosink is waiting.

Comment: For some odd reason, this boosts the CPU usage up by 40%. Why would this be, and what should I do to fix this?

Comment: @DK, don't know, but I'll try to investigate why this is the case

Comment: I had a problem with glimagesink where it was lagging so much and causing the audiosink to starve and I did not want to use a tee. This did the trick! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Its a one kind of **bug of decodebin2**

see i have tested some pipelines and get to know following things

**pipeline1:**

```
gst-launch filesrc location="filename" !
decodebin2 name=dec !
queue ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink dec. !
queue ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink
```

this pipeline1 works fine with all container formats like .mkv,.mp4,ogg

but when you give codec extencion file then it create problem which you have said

i have tested it with .h264 file

**pipeline2:**

```
 gst-launch filesrc location="smal.h264" ! decodebin2 name=dec ! queue !
 autovideosink dec. ! queue ! autoaudiosink
```

**pipeline3:**

```
 gst-launch filesrc location="smal.aac" ! decodebin2 name=dec ! queue !
 autovideosink dec. ! queue ! autoaudiosink
```

**all has same problem they are unable to preloading ahaead and unable to showing error of invalid pad connection**

if you try only single valid pad connection then they works fine

**pipeline4:**

```
 gst-launch filesrc location="smal.h264" ! decodebin2 ! autovideosink
```

**pipeline5:**

```
 gst-launch filesrc location="smal.aac" ! decodebin2 ! autoaudiosink
```

pipeline 4 and 5 works fine

even

```
gst-launch filesrc location="/home/dk/Music/Vangelis - Alpha.mp3" !
decodebin2 ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink
```

this will also works fine....

Now to understand this bug more and fixing it we need to study and change decodebin2 source code.........>!!!!